# Display <pre> content as is when fetching from database

Tags: php

I have something like this in my page

```
class Dog
{
    public $name;

    public function __construct()
    {
        # code...
    }

    public function setname(string $name = '')
    {
        # code...
    }

    public function getname()
    {
        # code...
    }
}
```

That display as you can see it, but when it was stored in the database and fetch it back.

it was display as

```
class Dog{    public $name;    public function __construct()    {        # code...    }    public function setname(string $name = '')    {        # code...    }    public function getname()    {        # code...    }}
```

is there a way to make it as is?
is it have to do with css? html? or database scaping?

EDIT

What I've tried so far is:

I capture the content using [ContentTools](http://getcontenttools.com/) and save to database this way

```
$content = trim($content, " \t\n\r\0\x0B");
$content = $database->real_escape_string($content) # mysqli
```

Comment: This all depends upon how it was when you captured it and what you did to it before storing it on the database. Why are you storing code on a database anyway

Comment: Does not a simple `echo '<pre>';` before displaying the data work as expected?

Comment: Have you already tried `<pre><code>class .....</code></pre>`?

Comment: echo '<pre>' would result inline

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? How did you check whether the line feeds are present or not? How do you run the output anyways?

Comment: Additionally, don't use irrelevant tags. The given code has no connection to the tags "database" or "css", or have you forgotten to share the missing parts?

Comment: I updated the question which include a portion of my code

Comment: ....and where's the code where you echo anything? Escaping a string through the database's methods should be done before inserting it, not before outputting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to show it on a webpage you should replace the line jumps with a `<br>` as this:

```
str_replace("\n", "<br/>", $str);
```

If you're only testing you can change the mime of the exit with this code (place it on the top of the php file):

```
header("Content-Type: text/plain");
```

Comment: This works for me, I just replace <br> all \n before saving to db

Comment: If it solved your question please mark the answer as good. Thx.